# COM server instance creation fails with error -2147024156

Tags: windows, com, windows-7

When I try to create a DCOM server with CoCreateInstance, it fails with error code  '-2147024156'. The error message corresponding to the error code is 'the process requires elevation'. What should I do to correct this issue?

Comment: It is not going to show you the UAC prompt.  You'll have to make this EXE work without requiring elevation.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I didn't undertand your comment. Can you make it clear?

Comment: Start this EXE from Windows Explorer.  What do you see?

Comment: A UAC dialog appears for Both Client and Server applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A UAC dialog appears for Both Client and Server applications

Right, and that's the problem.  There is no mechanism to display a UAC dialog on a remote machine.  That would utterly defeat the point of UAC.  You'll have to make it work without the dialog.  Replace "requireAdministor" in the manifest with "asInvoker" and adjust the code to not require the privilege.  Good luck with it.